# Periodical loss in test data with l2 regularization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, regularization, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow to implement a RNN (LSTM) network to classify a very small dataset (1500 samples) of timeseries (64 steps, 72 features) which represents movement. These samples could come from the same origin so you can have in both in train and test. Not the same movement but a similar one (because the same origin).

I'm using a stack of 4 basic LSTM with 24 hidden units:

```
# Linear activation
_X = tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden']

_X = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=n_steps, value=_X)

lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cell_3 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cell_4 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2, lstm_cell_3, lstm_cell_4], state_is_tuple=True)

# Get LSTM cell output
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)

# Linear activation
result = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

My loss function is:

```
class_weights = tf.constant([12.0, 26.0, 43.0, 17.0])
# deduce weights for batch samples based on their true label
weights = tf.reduce_sum(class_weights * y, axis=1)
unweighted_losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=pred)
weighted_losses = unweighted_losses * weights

#L2 Regularization
l2 = lambda_loss_amount * sum(
    tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables())

# Final loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean(weighted_losses) + l2
```

And the problem is that I'm getting a normal behaviour in the train data, but my test data is acting weird. [image: Accuracy][image: loss].

As you can see I having these ups and downs in loss and I don't know why. The first thing that I don't totally understand is how accuracy on test (blue) can stay the same while loss is growing that much? and the second thing is about how the machine learns and learns.. and then it fails? should I have try with smaller values of learning rates and still the same. Maybe you could give me some ideas about.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be a good fit here, we can see what people say. Are you looking for help w/ your code, or code check? (That would be off topic.)

Comment: Hi, @gung.  I just put my code to show my architecture and so. My question is more related to deep learning basis. I mean: I have read that using L2 regularization with LSTM is not a good idea and maybe this is what is happening (exploding gradient because L2 + clipping gradient because LSTM?). I was just looking for comments or ideas of what is going on. If I remove the L2 regularization, the 'ups and downs' stops, but I must apply some regularization in order to avoid overfitting.